# Python CSV: Loop Dates to Specific Column

Tags: python-2.7, csv

CSV File Output:

```
Date (Column Header)
Week, 5-Dec, 4-Dec, 3-Dec, 2-Dec, 1-Dec 
Week, 5-Dec, 4-Dec, 3-Dec, 2-Dec, 1-Dec
```

Outputs this for every row in the file.

Current Code:

```
import csv

with open("C:\E\cs2.csv", 'r') as input, open('date.csv', 'w') as output:
 reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
 writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',',lineterminator='\n')

 all = []
 row = next(reader)
 all.append(row)

for row in reader:        
   for d in ('Week','12-1','12-2','12-3','12-4','12-5'):
     row.insert(5,d)
     all.append(row)
writer.writerows(all)
```

Problem: Currently I am writing every date across each row, starting at the 6th column.  I would like to loop the specific dates listed above on the 6th column, but in a vertical fashion.

```
Desired Output on Column 6:
  Date(Column Header)
  Week
  12-1
  12-2, etc.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish the writing of the data vertically opposed to horizontally?

Comment: I tried the row.insert under the second loop. Then I tried to use  next(row), but that failed. I need to tell the second loop to go to the next line, that is what I have been trying to solve.